# Xamarin Forms Collection View duplicate

Tags: c#, .net, azure, xamarin.forms, azure-cosmosdb

In my Xamarin forms App, I am trying to get data from [Azure cosmos db](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/quickstart-dotnet?tabs=azure-portal%2Cwindows%2Cpasswordless%2Csign-in-azure-cli) and display it in my collectionView.

I successfully get data from Cosmos db but when I am trying to display by searching I have duplicated data in my collectionview

Here is how I get data from cosmos db :

```
    public async static Task<List<MyUser>> GetUserList(string MyFriendName)
{



    MyFriendName = MyFriendName.ToLower();
  
    List<MyUser> UsersList = new List<MyUser>();

    string sql =  "SELECT TOP 25 * FROM  " + collectionId + " u WHERE CONTAINS(LOWER(u.username),'"+ MyFriendName+ "') ";

    QueryDefinition query = new QueryDefinition(sql);
    


    using (FeedIterator<MyUser> iterator = container.GetItemQueryIterator<MyUser>(
     queryDefinition: query,
     requestOptions: new QueryRequestOptions()
     {
         MaxItemCount = -1,

     }))

    {
       
        while (iterator.HasMoreResults)
        {
            FeedResponse<MyUser> result = await iterator.ReadNextAsync();

            UsersList.AddRange(result.Resource);


        }

        return UsersList;



    }




}
```

Here is how I prepare to show the data from cosmos db:

```
    ObservableRangeCollection<MyCommunityModel> datasource;
MyCommunityModel CommunityUser;
async   Task<ObservableRangeCollection<MyCommunityModel>> OnPersonSearch(string MyFriendName)
{

    datasource.Clear();
    //get data from cosmos db function
    var UsersList =  await  UserManager.GetUserList(MyFriendName);


    foreach (var u in UsersList)
    {
        CommunityUser = new MyCommunityModel();

        CommunityUser.MyId = u.MyId;
        CommunityUser.Username = u.Username;

        var imageData = await AzureDatalakeBlob.GetFileAsync(AzureDatalakeBlob.ContainerType.leafwordsapp, CommunityUser.UserImageBlobAdress);

        if (imageData != null)
        {
            CommunityUser.UserImage = ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(imageData));
        }
        else
        {
            CommunityUser.UserImage = ImageSource.FromResource("LeafWords.MyImages.MySettings.person.png");
        }

                        
        datasource.Add(CommunityUser);
    }

    return datasource;

}
```

//Here is how I show data

```
void OnSearchCommunity(System.Object sender, Xamarin.Forms.TextChangedEventArgs e)
{


// show data 

    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
    {
         MyCommunityCollectionList.ItemSizingStrategy = ItemSizingStrategy.MeasureFirstItem;
            //display data here 
            MyCommunityCollectionList.ItemsSource = await OnPersonSearch(searchTerm);
    
    });
```

Comment: @user123456 Hello, thanks for your answer but please this is not the solution my issue

Comment: @hugo ok filter the data in the api side.UsersList.Where(x=>x.attribute =="")]

Comment: the data is already filtered when I make the call from GetUserList(string MyFriendName) function

Comment: Have you examined `UsersList` in debugger, to see if it contains duplicates?

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve yes because I am the one who created the database

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. To rule out the possibility that there is some code mistake, after the line `var UsersList =  await  UserManager.GetUserList...` runs, examine contents of variable `UsersList` in the debugger.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Yes you are right, the data are correct but the collection view is duplicated it

Comment: Put a breakpoint on line `datasource.Clear();`. When it stops there, continue. Does it get there a second time, before the data is displayed? That’s the only way I can see data getting doubled. It would be safer to move that clear down, after the `var UsersList = await …` line. This avoids possibility of second call coming between clear and filling of data. if two calls interleave: clear - await - clear - await - fill - fill, the result after second call would be doubled data.

Answer (score 0):

create api and call it

```
public async Task<List<TodoItem>> RefreshDataAsync ()
{
  ...
  Uri uri = new Uri (string.Format (Constants.TodoItemsUrl, string.Empty));
  ...
  HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync (uri);
  if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
  {
      string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync ();
      Items = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<TodoItem>>(content, serializerOptions);
  }
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- Put a breakpoint on line `datasource.Clear();`. When it stops there, continue. Does it get there a second time, before the data is displayed? That’s the only way I can see data getting doubled.

If two calls interleave: clear - await - clear - await - fill - fill, the result after second call would be doubled data.

- It would be safer to move that clear down, after the `var UsersList = await …` line. This avoids possibility of second call coming between clear and filling of data.

```cs
var UsersList =  await  UserManager.GetUserList(MyFriendName);
datasource.Clear();
foreach ..
  datasource.Add ..
```

Comment: Still not working but the i idea is good. sometimes when I want to type for instance "dog" so it will give me the result for "d", after " do" , after  "dog" but I do not know why it give me back the result for "d" and my collection view change again

Comment: Is there a way to make it follow the line : clear await fill . Always even if it type many times?

Comment: TextChanged is called as each character is typed. If it doesn't change collection each time, when do you want it to change?

Comment: I would like to each time  have " clear - await - fill" but sometime because of await it is not working and I have duplicated value

Answer (score 0):

You can try to define a global variable for the `ItemsSource` of your `CollectionView`:

```
  public ObservableCollection<MyCommunityModel> Items { get; set; }
```

And initialize it as follows:

```
  Items = new ObservableCollection<MyCommunityModel>();
```

Then when you get the data from database, you can assign the result to it.

For example:

```
 //get data from cosmos db function
 Items = await  UserManager.GetUserList(MyFriendName);
```

Note:

if the type of the result of `await  UserManager.GetUserList(MyFriendName)` is not `ObservableCollection<T>`, you can convert the result to `ObservableCollection<T>` and assign it to `Items`.

Then you no longer need to iterate through the result and add elements to it one by one,just as the following code you shared:

```
foreach (var u in UsersList)
{
    CommunityUser = new MyCommunityModel();

    CommunityUser.MyId = u.MyId;
    CommunityUser.Username = u.Username;
    datasource.Add(CommunityUser);
}
```

**Note:**

For how to display the result by searching key words, you can check the official document: [Xamarin.Forms SearchBar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/searchbar).

And there is a sample included in above link,you can check it here: [SearchBarDemos](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/main/UserInterface/SearchBarDemos).

Comment: I need to iterate because some data are null and I have condition on it

Comment: `I need to iterate because some data are null and I have condition on it`   Is there something wrong?